# Reliable configuration in Java 9

Tags: java, java-9

One of the main goals of project Jigsaw in Java 9 is the **reliable configuration**. That is, Java 9 promises to address the classpath mechanism flaw that allows the **java** launcher to run a program without making sure that all necessary classes will be available to load in runtime, which used to result in `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`s.

This is done by declaring module dependencies in `module-info.java` and by the brand new `--module-path` option. The module graph is analyzed before launching a Java application.

However, I can still do the following.

1. Lets say I have two modules `com.spacey.explorer` and `com.spacey.rocket`.  `com.spacey.explorer` uses a class `com.spacey.rocket.RocketZ` defined and exported by `com.spacey.rocket` module. After compiling and JARing both modules everything runs correctly.
2. Now I remove the `com.spacey.rocket.RocketZ` type from `com.spacey.rocket` module and recompile and re-JAR only this one module.
3. I run the previously compiled `com.spacey.explorer` module with newly compiled `com.spacey.rocket` module.
4. I get ... `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`, which is possible after like 4 hours of application uptime.

Is there a way to **really** make sure that when running Java application not only the module graph (module path) completeness is verified but also a comprehensive check of the actual type accessibility is done ?

Comment: No. The module system never checks for classes.

Comment: Could you elaborate what you meant by (3). How do you run the `c.s.explorer` with newly compiled `c.s.rocket` if there is a class missing in it?

Comment: @nullpointer Exactly the same as in (1) `java --module-path ../jars-dir --module com.spacey.explorer/com.spacey.explorer.MissionApp`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a way to **really** make sure that when running Java application not only the module graph (module path) completeness is verified but also a comprehensive check of the actual type accessibility is done?

Not within the JVM, no. The module system operates on the level of artifacts and is happy if an artifact claiming to be the right module [is present](https://blog.codefx.org/java/java-module-system-tutorial/#dependencies-readability). Beyond that, no further checks are performed.

That said, [JDeps](https://blog.codefx.org/tools/jdeps-tutorial-analyze-java-project-dependencies/) should be able to help you out. It analyzes your project and its dependencies and operates on the level of individual classes. It will point out dependencies that could not be found.

In your example:

```
$ jdeps -R --module-path jars-dir -m com.spacey.explorer

> com.spacey.explorer    -> com.spacey.rocket    not found
```

Comment: In fact **jdeps** can do the job. It is worth also adding the `-verbose:class` option to get more informative (class-level) output.

Answer (score 4):

I think the other answer helps on the technical aspect, but beyond that, I think you got the *reliable* part a bit wrong.

[This](https://thoughtfulsoftware.wordpress.com/2016/08/29/java-9-why-modules/) talks about *brittle* classpaths:

> All of these are the results of a brittle classpath. What that means is that ClassLoaders don’t have a good mechanism for distinguishing one loaded class from another class of the same name, or for isolating classes loaded by one ClassLoader from classes loaded by another.

And the answer that modules offer to this:

> Java Modules will provide reliable configuration and strong encapsulation. If you have incompatibilities, you will discover these at build time instead of some indeterminate time after your application has started running in production.

In other words: I think it is a misconception on your end to assume that modules were designed to prevent *all* kinds of [LinkageError](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/LinkageError.html) (the mother of all No..FoundError thingies). Modules make it easier for you to **build** things. You found a nice example that this doesn't necessarily translate into a perfect safety net regarding *runtime* issues.

In other words: your interpretation of "reliable modules" is not in sync with the promise of "reliable modules" that project Jigsaw is actually trying to provide.